# Formatting cells based on other cells

Tags: .net, excel, vb.net

I have a list of Clients imported in Excel, with 4 columns. The only ones I am interested in is Column1 which represents the clients' names, and Column4, which indicates if they have debts to pay by simply saying "Y" and "N". I want to write a small function that when the fourth column of a certain row says "N", the customer's name will be highlighted in red. If it's "Y", it will be highlighted in green. I have written this up until now

```
For i = 1 To 15
        Dim pay = oSheet.Range("D" & i).Find(What:="Y")
        If Not pay Is Nothing Then
            oSheet.Range("A" & i).Interior.ColorIndex = 4
        End If
    Next
    For i = 1 To 15
        Dim pay = oSheet.Range("D" & i).Find(What:="N")
        If pay Is Nothing Then
            oSheet.Range("A" & i).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
        End If
    Next
```

The problem I am encountering is that it seems my second **for** basically completely overwrites the first one and will simply change the colors of all my 15 rows. The first one will also modify all my rows regardless of what the respective column says. I am thinking that one of the code lines I am using actually searches all cells if it has "Y" or "N" on them, and not just one by one. Can you guys clarify for me what I am doing wrong, please?

Comment: Maybe use the debugger and check what value 'Dim pay = oSheet.Range("D" & i).Find(What:="N")' returns. Im no vba expert, but your code looks a bit different than the samples found online, so maybe just recheck that? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.find

Comment: You can't do that, `dim` as a variable type in one line, then do the `find` on another line.

Comment: How about the issue? Does the answer below resolved your question, If yes, you could Accept it as an Answer , so it could help other community members who get the same issues and we could archive this thread, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you forgot the **Not** in your second **If** statement. it should be:

```
For i = 1 To 15
    Dim pay = oSheet.Range("D" & i).Find(What:="Y")
    If Not pay Is Nothing Then
        oSheet.Range("A" & i).Interior.ColorIndex = 4
    End If
Next
For i = 1 To 15
    Dim pay = oSheet.Range("D" & i).Find(What:="N")
    If Not pay Is Nothing Then
        oSheet.Range("A" & i).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
    End If
Next
```